# react-native-camera crashes application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using `react-native-camera` for my application and testing in iPad(version 9.3.5) but my app crashes while I click on button to record video without displaying any error. I'm referring [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) tutorial.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: you should check with Xcode. it should throw some error.